# Simplify including dim of matrix as parameter

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

I want to check that an identity about matrix is true for all dim n.

My idea is to view dim n as a parameter and then `Simplify` the expression.

For example,I hope

```
Simplify[Sum[IdentityMatrix[n][[i, j]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]
```

will give n.But it warn that

```
Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification.
```

and just put out what I input.

Why this happened?How could I recorrect my code in the example so that it put out n?

Comment: maybe you need to specify the positive integer `n`. otherwise, `IdentityMatrix[n]` will not generate a matrix but leaves the form itself. so statements like `IdentityMatrix[n][[1,1]]` is illegal, and as the variable n is not given, `{i,1,n}` is illegal, so the warning appears.

Comment: Thanks! Then I guess I must try another way.